Getting error in MYSQL 8.0 installation - cannot create regular file '/var/log/mysqld.log
We have an application which uses MYSQL 8.0
We are trying to generate OVA file for our application which also installs MYSQL 8.0. We are using anaconda ks.cfg to generate Bootable ISO. From this bootable ISO, we generate ovf + vmdk to bring up our server.
When we try to create a new VM with this OVA file, we observed that, the below file is not created and we get an error
cannot create regular file '/var/log/mysqld.log
Since this file contains the temporary password for MYSQL, our MYSQL server is not coming up.
Any possible suggestions for this issue?
